# What is the different between R.anim.slide_left_in and R.anim.slide_left_out

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

What is the different between  `R.anim.slide_left_in` and `R.anim.slide_left_out` and also, 
`R.anim.slide_right_in` and `R.anim.slide_right_out`
I have the following xml for `slide_left_in`

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are named pretty descriptively...

`R.anim.slide_left_in` will slide the view in from the left.

`R.anim.slide_left_out` will slide the view out to the left.

Same thing for the `right` ones but in the opposite direction.

**EDIT:**

`R.anim.slide_left_out`

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

The right out/in ones will be roughly the same as the left ones but with positive 100% instead of negative.

Comment: thnaks can you help in writing in the xml res ?